# How do I get a value from a variable in another View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I'm trying to get the values from 4 different variables in PrefsViewController in ViewController but when PrefsViewController is dismissed the values reset.

#### Snippet of ViewController.swift

```swift
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSWindowDelegate { 
    
    var triesEnabled = false
    var minNumber = 0
    var maxNumber = 20
    var maxTries = 3
    
    @objc func applyPrefs() {
        let mainSB = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let prefsVC: PrefsViewController = mainSB.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "prefsViewController") as! PrefsViewController
        minNumber = prefsVC.prefsMinNum
        maxNumber = prefsVC.prefsMaxNum
        triesEnabled = prefsVC.prefsTriesEnabled
        maxTries = prefsVC.prefsMaxTries
        print("\(minNumber) \(maxNumber) \(triesEnabled) \(maxTries)") // here I can see that it has been reset to the default values
        resetGame(minRange: minNumber, maxRange: maxNumber, isTriesEnabled: triesEnabled, triesLimit: maxTries)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applyPrefs), name: Notification.Name("notifyApplyPrefs"), object: nil )
        resetGame(minRange: minNumber, maxRange: maxNumber, isTriesEnabled: triesEnabled, triesLimit: maxTries)
    }
}
```

#### Snippet of PrefsViewController

```swift
class PrefsViewController: NSViewController {
    
    var triesOn = false
    
    var prefsMinNum: Int = 0
    var prefsMaxNum: Int = 20
    var prefsTriesEnabled: Bool = false
    var prefsMaxTries: Int = 3
    
    @IBAction func closeButton(_ sender: Any) {
        if (!minNumTextField.stringValue.isInt || !maxNumTextField.stringValue.isInt || !triesTextField.stringValue.isInt) {
            let alert = NSAlert()
            alert.messageText = "Error"
            alert.informativeText = "You can only enter (whole) numbers in the text fields."
            alert.alertStyle = .warning
            alert.addButton(withTitle: "OK")
            alert.runModal()
            return
        }
        prefsMinNum = Int(minNumTextField.intValue)
        prefsMaxNum = Int(maxNumTextField.intValue)
        prefsTriesEnabled = triesOn
        prefsMaxTries = Int(minNumTextField.intValue)
        
        print("minNumTextField: \(prefsMinNum) maxNumTextField: \(prefsMaxNum) triesCheckBox: \(prefsTriesEnabled) triesTextField: \(prefsMaxTries)")
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("notifyApplyPrefs"), object: nil)
        self.dismiss(self)
    }
}
```

The prefs view is shown as a sheet (I don't know if that's important)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `instantiateController` you're creating a new, never before used, instance of the controller.  If you want to have the data transferred using a notification, send `self` as the object when you call `post` and then use that to get your variables.

You would also need to change `applyPrefs` so that it takes a Notification parameter so that the notification object is available to you.

Comment: Thanks! How do I make applyPrefs tase a notification parameter?

Comment: `func applyPrefs(_ notification: Notification)` and when posting `object: self`

Comment: This looks like a reasonable example: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/observers-in-swift-part-1/